# Unclear Index of Sum

Tags: summation

I'm facing this sum of products $\sum_{j, k=1; j\neq k}^{3}\theta_j \theta_k$.

Now, does this mean

${1\times2 + 1\times3 + 2\times1 + 2\times3 + 3\times1 + 3\times2}$

or just

${1\times2 + 1\times3 + 2\times3}$?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there's a $g$ in the formula?

Comment: The first, after putting in the $\theta$'s.

Comment: The $g$ is in the formula, I just added the $=3$ to signal that it goes from $1$ to $3$.

Comment: okay, I've edited accordingly, now it should be clearer.

Comment: Assuming your numbers refer to the indices of $\theta$ then it is the top one.  There is no restriction of the form $j<k$.

Comment: @lulu Yes they do. Okay thanks, that's what I thought. Hopefully the author used the formula accurately.